# AVPlayerのボタンイベントを取得したい

Tags: swift, ios

AVPlayerViewControllerを用いて、動画の再生をさせているのですが、
Playerに渡した動画の再生が終わったら、早送り・スキップボタン（>>|）で次の動画を再生するようにしたいと考えています。
しかし、肝心のボタンイベントを取得する方法がわかりません。

次のような動作を考えています。
１．AVPlayerControllerの再生画面を生成
２．再生する動画をPlayerに渡す
３．再生する
４．最後まで再生、止まる
５．早送り・スキップボタンを押す
６．ボタン押下イベントを認識←ここがわからない！！
７．次の動画を読み込む
８．読み込みが終わったら次の動画を再生

自動的に次の動画を再生するのではなく、ボタンでスキップしたら次の動画をセットして再生するようにしたいのですが、手段はありませんでしょうか。

色々調べてみたのですが解決せず困っています。
すみません、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

最近存在を知ったReactiveの方法はどうでしょうか？自分が参考にさせていただいているURL載せときます。
と言っても最初の方に書いてあるものしかまだ理解できていない自分ですが……それだけでも、少し使ってみるだけでも便利！と思います！
http://qiita.com/yoching/items/ea0cee3669de1e3fa4fb

内容としてはcodeは上から流れるものなのですが、これを使うことによってもう流れたcodeの所に通知をして実装を変換してくれるというものです。ボタンのアクションは1とかなんでもいいのですが、通知がきてそれが1だったらとかそんな感じでやったらできるのかもと思いました。

Comment: リンクをはっていただいたサイトを参考にReactiveについて勉強してみます！ありがとうございます！

Comment: きっと、役にたつことを願います。私も色々勉強して、詳しくなれるように頑張りたいと思います⭐️